# c++: function that returns current key input as any type

Tags: c++

Previously, I used `GetAsyncKeyState()` from `windows.h` and ran a `while (true)` loop every case that press key.

But, it uses much CPU usage, even `Sleep(50)`->'0.05sec' every one loop.

If the Windows OS is already checking keys, do I have ways to get the key state **from the OS**? If I do that, will CPU usage be lower?

Anyway, please help me to know an easy way to get current key inputs.

For example, if the user is pressing <kbd>A</kbd> & <kbd>B</kbd> & <kbd>Home</kbd> at same time, the function that I imagine returns `{'A','B','Home'}` as any string or other type.

addition:
The code that I write is like this.

```
if (getasynckeystate('A') != 0)
{
    IsA = true; //bool
}
else
{
    IsA = false; 
}
//skip......
```

It runs to all of key (Fnkey,num,word,etc...)
It looks uneffective even to me.

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: Do you actually need the global keyboard state? If you have a window like many apps do, you get messages when a key is pressed. If you do really need global state, there are still options that don't require polling such as registering a hotkey or using a hook. It really depends on what your app is trying to do.

Comment: Have you looked at this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-keydown

Comment: Typically if you need that kind of constant key state tracking, you are creating a game which re-draws (or tries to) the screen every 18 milliseconds (60 Hz) or something like that anyway. In this kind of scenario, checking the keys at every game loop iteration should be no extra CPU usage. If you are not working on this kind of "real-time" application, then you want to just wait for events from the OS, not ask key states (or mouse position or anything else) yourself. In other words, you need to turn your main loop logic the other way around.

Comment: "and ran a while (true)" Why? What were you trying to do with this loop?

Answer (score 3):

`GetAsyncKeyState` *is* the OS; therefore your question doesn't make much sense.

But the broader answer is that you should not be polling for keyboard states like this. Instead, you should be listening for when the OS tells your application that a key was pressed. This is via a [message loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/using-messages-and-message-queues) and handling `WM_CHAR` or [`WM_KEYDOWN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-keydown), et al. *This* is how you solve the (perceived) performance problem. This way instead of your code running every N milliseconds, it runs only when the keyboard state changes.

Other advantages:

- This will follow the behavior of keyboard focus. So when your application is not focused, it will not respond to keyboard events (which users would not expect)
- Polling will fail to recognize very quick key presses if it lands between polls. WM_KEYDOWN will handle *all* keyboard presses with no jitter and no gaps.
- `GetAsyncKeyState` gets the current keyboard state, which (maybe unintuitively) does not always match what the user expects. For example if the user hits a key at the moment your application freezes for a bit, users expect the key to still register. That's standard behavior and if you use `GetAsyncKeyState`, the keypress will be lost and the user will be forced to press it again. The experience is that users feel that your application is not reliable.

Another note about performance though: Calling `GetAsyncKeyState` every 50ms should not cause significant CPU usage. I suspect if there really is a performance issue, it's not been described in your question.